# How do I make sure a flask app has been authorized on all routes?

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I am, still, a n00b in Python and Flask. I am creating routes using flask for an API. I am integrating with the GitHub API using GitHub-Flask. Is there an easy and consistent way to check for a current access/request token before executing code for each route? Other than copy/pasting the same check all over the place, hopefully; which is currently what I am doing.

```
@app.route('/resource_1', methods=['GET'])
def get_resource_1():
  if not ACCESS_TOKEN:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

  # ... do stuff for route

@app.route('/resource_2', methods=['GET'])
def get_resource_2():
  if not ACCESS_TOKEN:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

  # ... do other stuff for this route
```

I imagine there is a much better way that this but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: I did find this link - http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/125/ - but I am unsure how to adapt it to my problem. I know the solution is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to protect certain routes, you can use a view decorator.  This would look something like this:

```
  from functools import wraps
  from flask import g, request, redirect, url_for

    def login_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if not ACCESS_TOKEN:
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
```

Then you decorate each resource like so:

```
@app.route('/resource_2', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_resource_2():
```

View decorators are documented here: 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/

If you want to protect absolutely every request then you can use the before_request handler on either the app or the blueprint level:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if not ACCESS_TOKEN:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Not to be too greedy but would there also be a way to redirect back to the original route after invoking the login?

Comment: You can pass the original url as a parameter on the request or you can store it in the session and check for it on the before_request handler. This is a very common pattern.  Why not look in the source for some of the flask login packages or better, why not just use one!

Comment: Also mark the answer as correct, if you found it so.  I'm greedy for points lately.

Comment: arrg.. this is not a good pattern. as question states "all routes" need to be authorized by default. i don't want to rely on everyone putting a decorator on every endpoint going forward. I've been stuck with this for hours trying to make app.before_request work but that event doesn't seem to show custom headers :/

Comment: What's wrong with the before_request approach then?

Comment: Where does ACCESS_TOKEN come from, though?